# Firebase Database reference snapshot is not returning any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read some dummy data I have put into my Firebase database but cannot get it to return anything despite trying my best with following the documentation.

I have a JS file with Firebase initialized, and with this variable exported:

```
const database = firebase.database();
```

In a file I'm trying to read it in, I have the below:

```
import database from './firebase';
const dbRef = database.ref('users/');
dbRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Nothing gets logged out into the console. But when I log out just dbRef, I get the Reference object so it does seem to be connected properly:

```
Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
database: (...)
key: (...)
orderByCalled_: false
parent: (...)
path: Path {pieces_: Array(1), pieceNum_: 0}
queryParams_: QueryParams {limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, endSet_: false, endNameSet_: false, …}
ref: (...)
repo: Repo {repoInfo_: RepoInfo, app: FirebaseAppImpl, dataUpdateCount: 0, statsListener_: null, eventQueue_: EventQueue, …}
root: (...)
__proto__: Query
```

I can't find where I've went wrong, would really appreciate the help. In my Firebase console, I am using Cloud Firestore by default rather than Realtime Database, not sure if that's making a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the Realtime Database API instead of the Firestore API.  They are not at all the same database, and they don't share the same API.  Use the [Firestore docs to get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).  You will use `firebase.firestore()` instead of `firebase.database()`.  [The API docs for Firestore start here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore).

Comment: Thank you, I must have went down the wrong pathway going through the documentation, did not realize there was a different set for Firestore